# Re-enable root access in mysql

Tags: mysql, root-access

I recently installed mysql on my (cloud) server and then I ran `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` and disallowed remote root login. Then I created another user to run all my queries and gave it appropriate permissions. I can't remember the password now (or password got changed somehow) and am unable to connect to mysql. Whenever I try to connect using `mysql -u user -p` I get the following error

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried following what answers to other question here on SO suggested but most of them require access to mysql shell.

I also tried to reconfigure using 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` (my version number is 5.5.41).

Using this I am able to set the root password but still can't connect it. I also tried running mysql in safe mode, as suggested by some user, with no luck.

Last thing I could think of was somehow renable the remote access for root, since I can reset it's password, and then reset the `user` password through mysql shell. So, I tried looking the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file but didn't see anything relevant.

Is there anything I am missing? How can I reset the password and get access again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop MySQL service

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Exec MySQL server with --skip-grant-tables

```
#mysqld -u mysql --skip-grant-tables &
```

Exec mysql client as root

```
#mysql -u root
```

Update your password

```
mysql> update mysql.user set password=password('newpassword') where user='anotheruser';
```

Reload privileges

```
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Kill mysqld

```
#killall mysql
```

Start mysql daemon

```
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Thank you. I had actually tried this but failed because i was putting `mysql` instead of `mysqld` while running mysql with `skip-grant-table &` option.

Comment: This answer still works except that in version 5.7.20, the password field name is no longer called password.  It is called authentication_string.

Comment: I needed to run with `sudo mysqld -u root --skip-grant-tables &`

Comment: Same situation, Ubuntu 22.04. The problem for me is that when I type "mysql -u root" then I have an error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  mysqld -u mysql --skip-grant-tables`